# The number of ways to merge a permutation with itself

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let $\sigma$ be a permutation of $[k]=\{1,2, \dots , k\}$. Consider all the ordered triples $(\pi, s_{1},s_{2})$, such that $\pi$ is a permutation of length $2k-1$ that is a union of its two subsequences $s_{1}$ and $s_{2}$, each of which is of length $k$ and is order-isomorphic to $\sigma$.

Example:

$\sigma = 312$,

If $\pi = 54213$, then there are $4$ such triples:

1. $(\pi, 523,413)$
2. $(\pi, 513,423)$
3. $(\pi, 413,523)$
4. $(\pi, 423,513)$

Indeed, each of the listed sequences $s_{1}$ and $s_{2}$, namely $523$, $413$, $513$ and $423$ are order isomorphic to $\sigma=312$, i.e., if the triple is $xyz$, then $x>z>y$.

Denote the number of these triples by $N_{2k-1}^{\sigma}$. Prove that $N_{2k-1}^{\sigma}>\binom{2k-1}{k}^{2}$ for every $\sigma$.

Example: $k=2$. It suffices to show that $N_{3}^{21}>\binom{3}{2}^{2}=9$ since $N_{3}^{21}=N_{3}^{12}.$ In fact, we have 10 triples that are listed below:

$\sigma = 321$: $(321,32,31)$, $(321,31,32)$, $(321,32,21)$, $(321,21,32)$, $(321,31,21)$, $(321,21,31)$.

$\sigma = 312$: $(312,31,32)$, $(312,32,31)$.

$\sigma = 231$: $(231,21,31)$, $(231,31,21)$.

Generalisation: For $1\leq v \leq k$, denote by $N_{2k-v}^{\sigma}$ the number of the triples $(\pi, s_{1},s_{2})$ for which $\pi$ is of length $2k-v$ and $s_{1}$ and $s_{2}$ have $v$ common elements. Prove that $N_{2k-v}^{\sigma}>\binom{2k-v}{k}^{2}$ for every $\sigma$. Note that for $v=k$, we always have $1$ triple and the conditions holds trivially. Can we proceed by induction? When $v=0$, we obviously have $N_{2k}^{\sigma} = \binom{2k}{k}^{2}$ for every $\sigma$ of length $k$.

Idea: One might choose two subsets of numbers $A,B\subset[2k-v]$, that after an appropriate transformation would be the elements of $s_{1}$ and $s_{2}$. In other words, a simple injective map from $\binom{[2k-v]}{k}^{2}$ to the set of triples might exist that would solve the problem, but I cannot see it.